# Inserting new column into an R data frame, but the values are being stored as "named list"

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a very simple function which takes in a DF, groups it and does counts on some columns.
Then, I take that grouped DF and I add a new column to it, using a vector that contains the results of some calculations done upon the values of one of the existing columns (getting the % of the value)

However, in the output, my new column is of type named List. I attempted to wrap the vector in `dfSubset$Percentage` <- in `as.numeric()` but this only resulted in the numbers being the same as those in `Amount` column but with 2 zeros appended at the end

```
calculateMatchRate <- function(df) {
  dfSubset <- df %>% group_by(`Match Flag`) %>% tally(name="Amount")
  dfSubset$Percentage <- c((dfSubset[1,2] / (nrow(dfSubset) -1) * 100), (dfSubset[2,2] / (nrow(dfSubset) - 1) * 100))
  
  return(dfSubset)
}
```

The MRE would be

```
df <- data.frame("Match Flag" = c('N', 'Y'), "Amount" = c(15645, 92294))
calculateMatchRate(df)
```

Expected output:

```
#total rows in file are 107939
#The ~ sign is not part of the code, I'm just saying I expect the data to be around that

Match Flag | Amount | Percentage
    N         15645      ~14.50
    Y         92294      ~85.50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this function :

```
library(dplyr)

calculateMatchRate <- function(df) {

  dfSubset <- df %>% 
                group_by(Match.Flag) %>% 
                tally(name="Amount") %>%
    mutate(Percentage = Amount/sum(Amount) * 100)
  return(dfSubset)
}

calculateMatchRate(df)
```

You can also use `count` here instead of `tally` :

```
calculateMatchRate <- function(df) {
  dfSubset <- df %>% 
                count(Match.Flag, name = 'Amount') %>%
                mutate(Percentage = Amount/sum(Amount) * 100)
  return(dfSubset)
}
```

---

The reason why OP's method returned a named list is because `(dfSubset[1,2] / (nrow(dfSubset) -1) * 100` returns a dataframe and when we combine two dataframes with `c` it makes it as a list with column names being the names of the list. The reason why `(dfSubset[1,2] / (nrow(dfSubset) -1) * 100` returns a dataframe is because `dfSubset` is a tibble and tibbles don't drop dimensions when we subset them tibbles. When we do `dfSubset[1,2]` it still returns a tibble. A quick fix would to be to turn `dfSubset` into dataframe.

```
calculateMatchRate <- function(df) {
  dfSubset <- df %>% group_by(`Match.Flag`) %>% tally(name="Amount") %>% as.data.frame()
  dfSubset$Percentage <- c((dfSubset[1,2] / (nrow(dfSubset) -1) * 100), (dfSubset[2,2] / (nrow(dfSubset) - 1) * 100))
  
  return(dfSubset)
}
```

and then calling `calculateMatchRate(df)` should give the output as new column.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Do you know the reason why my method was resulting in a named list? It puzzles me especially because I never even named said list.

Comment: I updated the answer to include some explanation for that behaviour.